# Converting SQL Server script to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

There is this script in the SQL Server that needs to be converted in PostgreSQL.
Here is the script:

```
UPDATE Categories_convert SET Categories_convert.ParentID = 
Categories_convert_1.CategoryID 
FROM Categories_convert LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories_convert AS 
Categories_convert_1 ON Categories_convert.MainGroupID_FK = 
Categories_convert_1.MainGroupID 
WHERE (((Categories_convert.Level)=2));
```

Then I  tried to convert it to postgres. Here is the script:

```
UPDATE x_tmp_categories_convert SET orig.parentid = 
cat2.categoryid 
FROM x_tmp_categories_convert LEFT OUTER JOIN x_tmp_categories_convert AS 
cat2 ON x_tmp_categories_convert.maingroupid_fk = 
x_tmp_categories_convert.maingroupid 
WHERE (((cat.level)=2));
```

Note that I have already created the table **Categories_convert** of SQLServer to Postgresql and renamed it to **x_tmp_categories_convert** .
All the fields in postgresql is in lowercase.

Now the problem is when i execute the converted script to postgresql, an error will occur:

> ERROR: table name "x_tmp_categories_convert" specified more than once
>   SQL state: 42712

What I do wrong in the conversion?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer but it didn't update the records at all. The **parentid** field is still empty. It is supposed to map all the parentid of that categor based on its maingoupid_fk.

Below is a snapshot of the records after executing the suggested script.
I have opted out the name for disclosure reasons.

[Records snapshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlXDg.png)

**UPDATE v2:**
I am using php to migrate the data so pardon me for the variables used.
Here are the 2 insert statements used before the questioned update script is executed:

```
INSERT INTO x_tmp_categories_convert(maingroupid,name,vendorid,level,parentid)
VALUES ($id,'$mainGroup',$vendorID,1,Null);

INSERT INTO x_tmp_categories_convert(subgroupid,maingroupid_fk,name,vendorid,level)
VALUES ($id,'$mainGroupId','$subGroup',$vendorID,2);
```

Also, this is the table definition of the x_tmp_categories_convert table:

```
CREATE TABLE x_tmp_categories_convert
(
  categoryid serial NOT NULL,
  parentid double precision,
  name character varying(255),
  level double precision,
  vendorid double precision,
  maingroupid integer,
  subgroupid integer,
  maingroupid_fk integer,
  pageid integer,
  subgroupid_fk integer,
  CONSTRAINT code_pk PRIMARY KEY (categoryid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

**UPDATE v3:**
Already **SOLVED** by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name). Thank you

Comment: Please add sample data and table definitions as _formatted_ text (ideally as SQL insert statements), [no screenshots please](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I have added the additional info to the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have updated the question. Please

Answer (score 0):

I have edited @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer and to make it work. I guess it is just a copy paste error.

Here is the final script:

```
UPDATE x_tmp_categories_convert 
   SET parentid = cat.categoryid 
FROM x_tmp_categories_convert AS cat
WHERE x_tmp_categories_convert.maingroupid_fk = cat.maingroupid 
AND x_tmp_categories_convert.level = 2;
```

For @a_horse_with_no_name, I am very grateful to you as I cannot come up with the solution without your help. +1 for you man. Thank you

Comment: I deleted my answer because it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It is ok though. I just thought of it as a stepping stone in solving my problem. Before you answered my thread, I have no idea that i could do a simple script without joining the table. And 1 thing, your answer is correct. You just copy paste error 1 word in you solution.  Instead of "cat.level = 2", I just changed it to "x_tmp_categories_convert.level = 2" . So, I'm pretty sure that is what you meant when you answered my question. Thank you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Also, please add your answer again so that I can mark it as the answer.